# column name of max no in a row

Tags: vba, excel

Column header for different sheet

iI have many rows having data in sheet 2 and iI want the column name of the max of a row (i.e. from column from column name of B2 to AH2 inside if loop).

```
Sub shanaya()

    Dim j As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim z As Integer
    Dim x As Integer

    z = 35
    For i = 11 To 28
        For j = 2 To 19
            If Sheet8.Cells(j, 1) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1) Then
                Sheet1.Cells(i, 10) = Sheet8.Cells(j, z)
                Max [(Sheet8.Cells(J,2)): (Sheet8.Cells(j,z))]
                Sheet1.Cells(i,13) = column header of max function             
            End If     
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a minute to take the [tour] (click it) to learn how SO works! ;)

Comment: `WORKSHEETFUNCTION.MAX` then `WORKSHEETFUNCTION.INDEX` then `OFFSET` and `ADDRESS`.  or just do it as a formula.  If data a to h, something like `=CHAR(65+MATCH(MAX(A16:H16),A16:H16,0)-1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `MATCH` worksheet function will give you the column matching the `MAX` :

There is a `+1` because your range start at col 2! ;)

```
Sub shanaya()
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim z As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim ColOfMax As Integer
    Dim RgToSearch As Range

    z = 35
    For i = 11 To 28
        For j = 2 To 19
            If Sheet8.Cells(j, 1) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1) Then
                Sheet1.Cells(i, 10) = Sheet8.Cells(j, z)
                Set RgToSearch = Sheet8.Range(Sheet8.Cells(j, 2), Sheet8.Cells(j, z))
                ColOfMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(RgToSearch), RgToSearch, 0) + 1

                Sheet1.Cells(i, 13) = Sheet8.Cells(1, ColOfMax)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: run time error 1004 unable to get the max property of the worksheet function class

Comment: @AnkitSingh : Give the edit a try and please take the [tour]

Comment: thank you very much i just have a query what if there are two cells with same no can i get name of both column header

Comment: @AnkitSingh : Glad it worked! :) You could, but you'll most probably need to loop again on the range to test each cells against the max! :/ As this worked, thx to accept my answer! ;)

Comment: hello sir again... I am also happy it worked but i want all the coulmn headers having max no is a single cell like D/E/H. is it possible